# Android Webview explicit page unload or stop previous page java script activities

Tags: android, ajax, webview

I have a web based android application which uses Webview, it connects to a remote HTTP Server and brings HTML pages to be rendered in Webview. Each HTML page have some controls and every control action triggers a HTTP POST ajax request to the server. When the page loads, it first issues HTTP POST ajax requests to update the control states. Every new page which comes from the server gets reloaded/refreshed(using JS 'setInterval') in every 5 minutes.

The problem is that in the Webview when the page transits to a new page, the previous page Java Script activities still continues and hence the previous page AJAX requests increases the network bandwidth.

Is there a solution to stop the Javascript activities of the previous page in the webview, so that only the current/active page script works.

Preferably the solution should still have cache enabled, I want to avoid bringing in same pages from the server in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to make a Stop() method in your javascript and then call that from within your app. There are several ways to do that including creating some complex handles through the webview object but you can also just call it through the webview.LoadUrl() method.

Comment: I want to just stop the page refresh of the previous pages & hence their corresponding AJAX requests(which are happening in the background) which was set by the below code in the page's JS

$(document).ready(function(){
 var refreshId = setInterval(function()
 {
  doStatus(); //issues various AJAX requests
 }, 5000);
});

Actually I'm not explicitly loading new pages currently,every page that come from the server is navigating in/out to other pages by html links in it.
I just load the first page using the webview.loadUrl.

Comment: Does that means hooking the page transitions & invoking 'stop' method on the current pages before loading the next page?